# Need help installing DDrescue on Ubuntu 16.04 thumb drive

Tags: ddrescue

I've done it before but I had to re-purposed that USB drive and I can't seem to figure out how I got ddrescue installed the first time around. Which file do I need from here http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/ddrescue/ and, once copied to my bootable thumb drive, how can I install it so I can access it via terminal?

I'm new to Linux so I need step by step if possible.

Comment: You do not need persistence that `sudo apt update && sudo apt install ddrescue`

Comment: @Panther: I believe that's the answer.

Answer (score 15):

I use `ddrescue` installed from the universe repository in my installed system.

You can install it in a live-only or persistent live system too. In that case you need to add 'universe' to standard Ubuntu (while it is already there in the live systems of many of the community flavours, for example Lubuntu),

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
```

and then run

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install gddrescue
```

***note:`gddrescue` is the name of the package, which contains the program `ddrescue`***

The following link contains a description of how to use it to clone a failing drive,

[Repair the partition table and file system of a pendrive](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2196858&p=13409986#post13409986)

Scroll down to "Advanced repair of a partition table, file system and/or recovery of files"

Please notice that the manual (the info page)

```
info ddrescue
```

is very good. You can try according to one of the examples (in `info ddrescue`).